# Property of hermitian matrices (eigen values)

Tags: matrices

In a paper I have read the following

${\bf G}$ is a Hermitian matrix, that

1) ${\bf G}$ is diagonalizable

2) the singluar values are same as the eigen values

Is number 2 correct? I cant seem to find the proof

Thanks

Comment: The second point follows from the first and the fact that $G^TG=G^2$.

Comment: Number 2 is *not* correct. Singular values of a Hermitian matrix are equal to its eigenvalues in *absolute value*. To see this, consider the spectral decomposition $G=UDU^*$ (diagonal of $D$ is real). Note that $G=U\Sigma V^*$ is SVD of $G$ with $\Sigma=|D|$ and $V=U\,\mathrm{sgn}(D)$.